# Cannot see branch history on github

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I am new to Git and Github. I am using terminal to use git commands. So, I create a repository on Github. I clone it on my local machine. Then, if I create a branch using git command, I can see that I am switching branch. I am able to edit the code in that branch and I am able to merge the branch to master branch as well.

When I check on Github, I don't see any history of the branches that I have made and all the changes that I make in other branches and merge them to master, they still are portrayed as a single change made on the master branch on Github when I push the code.

I would like to know how my changes in branch and merging can be reflected in Github and some relevant resource about this will be helpful.

Comment: Have you pushed the local branches and new commits to the Github repository?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check the commit as graph in github by below steps:

Insights page -> Network tab.

[image]

All of your branches of the github repo will show as graph, and you can find the relation and actions between branches by the graph.

---

For fast-forward merge:

If your commit history looks as below:

```
...---A---B---C   master 
               \
                D---E  somebranch
```

Since there have been no new changes on `master` branch, when you merge `somebranch` into `master` (`git merge somebranch`), `master` branch will point to the commit `E` same as `somebranch` point:

```
...---A---B---C---D---E   master, somebranch
```

Comment: when I create a branch in my terminal with git branch somebranch, and checkout to this branch, work on this branch on my local machine. Commit changes and push it. Then I checkout to master branch and merge somebranch with master. When I do this, I get the changes in the master branch, but on the github, I don't see any branches that were made. Though, I can see the commit visible from the sombranch, but github shows that commit was made on master branch.

Comment: How did you merge `somebranch` into `master` branch, do you merged with default manner or merged with squash/rebase? The graph shows in github should be consistent with your local commit history. Can you show the screen shots both for local repo graph (use the command `gitk --all`) and github repo graph?

Comment: I am following this document to each step: [link] (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-a-git-branch-to-merge-a-file-681902555.html) Everything is done in terminal.

Comment: @PushkarKadam Based on the link you provide, it's fast-forward merge, so it looks like liner. I add the graphs for fast-forwrd merge in the end of my answer, you can compare with  your real commit history.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in a GitHub private repository, which is a shame, because I'm teaching a class I need to check student's work as well as teach them how to look at their own graph of commits.